# Incoming ssh connections are being made to native sshd and not Homebrew OpensSSH sshd

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, mac-osx

Incoming ssh connections appear to be made to the native (MacOSX) sshd and not to the Homebrew installed OpensSSH sshd

I have a vm linux ubuntu server 18.0.4 and Macbook running Osx 10.14.6
Both have an account for user the bbb and I can connect successfully to each from each without problem.

The macbook has openssh installed via homebrew
ssh -V

> OpenSSH_8.0p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019
>   Which ssh 
>   /usr/local/bin/ssh
>   As expected 
>   (Note the original Mac osx version is in /etc/ssh and is version 7.9)

However when I connect TO the macbook FROM the vm ubuntu machine the connection is apparently made to the OSX shh version 7.9 and not the homebrew version 8.0

This can be seen connecting from the ubuntu server (172.116.36.1290 to the macbook 10.10.2.3 with command

```
ssh -v bbb@10.10.2.3
>
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 10.10.2.3 [10.10.2.3] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/bbb/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/bbb/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/bbb/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/bbb/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/bbb/.ssh/id_ecdsa type 2
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/bbb/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/bbb/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/bbb/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.9
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.9 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
(..... login is successful)
```

Similarly
Scanning the mac osx ssh server from the ubuntu with nmap

```
sudo nmap --script ssh2-enum-algos -sV -p 22 10.10.2.3
>
[sudo] password for bbb:

Starting Nmap 7.60 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2019-09-23 03:25 UTC
Nmap scan report for 10.0.2.3
Host is up (0.0011s latency).

PORT   STATE SERVICE VERSION
22/tcp open  ssh     OpenSSH 7.9 (protocol 2.0)
| ssh2-enum-algos:
|   kex_algorithms: (10)
.......etcetera
```

Furthermore repeating a reverse connection from the macbook 10.10.2.3 to the ubuntu server 172.116.36.129

```
ssh -v bbb@172.116.36.129
>
OpenSSH_8.0p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019
debug1: Reading configuration data /usr/local/etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to 172.116.36.129 [172.116.36.129] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/bbb/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/bbb/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/bbb/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/bbb/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/bbb/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/bbb/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/bbb/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/bbb/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/bbb/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/bbb/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.0
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3 pat OpenSSH_7.0*,OpenSSH_7.1*,OpenSSH_7.2*,OpenSSH_7.3*,OpenSSH_7.4*,OpenSSH_7.5*,OpenSSH_7.6*,OpenSSH_7.7* compat 0x04000002
(..... login is successful)
```

which shows the expected homebrew version 8.0!!!

I dont get this can anyone help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you need help with, exactly?

Comment: Incoming ssh connections to macbook appear to be made to the native MacOSX sshd. I want to stop that embedded service and make connections to the Homebrew installed sshd

Answer (score 1):

SSH is two-part program: there is a server, called SSH Daemon and it is contained in binary 'sshd', and also there is a client, you run it as 'ssh'.

Server binary usually resides in ../sbin, because it needs to possibly bind to privileged port 22 and therefore is considered superuser-only executable.

All your "evidence" shows that the client (ssh) you use from MacOS is your homebrew one. But you didn't checked anything about server (sshd).

It seems, in your case, system still running its bundled sshd from default location, and it is bound to a port 22. To bind another program there you need to stop old one first.

So, if you want to run your sshd on the default port, you have to disable bundled sshd. You also can run them both on different ports, one of them will use non-default port. For that, in sshd_config:

```
...
Port 22222
...
```

Then, to connect use 'ssh -p 22222 user@address'.

Comment: Thanks: Your suggestion did not resolve the issue. As you proposed I edited sshd_config of the bundled sshd (/etc/ssh) to 2222

Comment: Thanks: however your suggestion did not resolve the issue. As you proposed I edited sshd_config of the bundled sshd (/etc/ssh) to 2222 re-booted. Subsequently I was still able to connect on port 22 - BUT with the same findings OpenSSH 7.9 (Connection on -p 2222 was denied) .  Further I edited sshd_config of the homebrew (/usr/local/etc/ssh) to 2221 re-booted. Oddly with both of the sshd_config files now on non-stantard ports I can still connect on port 22 with the same findings OpenSSH 7.9. i am very puzzeld

Comment: This could only mean the config file you modified isn't the one (or isn't the only one) which is acually being used by the server. Or, the server is configured not only by the file. For instance, "-p" option of sshd command line could also specify the port to bind to. There is also "ListenAddress" config file option which could also specify port. Read "man sshd" and "man sshd_config". Also learn how to find out PID of running process and how to find a path to executable which is associated with that PID.

Comment: Thanks - I will try the PID approach

Comment: This turned out to be a MAC OSX issue - The native mac sshd runs through configuration not accessible to the user (mac system integrity protection) however it is possible to disable (turn off) the osx ssh server. With that done runing the Homebrew installed sshd was an issue of figuring out how to use the mac equivalent of xinetd. I created a file (.plist) and placed it in ~/Library/LaunchAgents. The contents of the file were such that at startup it ran the homebrew sshd

Comment: In case others are interested the files was

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyLi$
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>Label</key>
  <string>homebrew.mxcl.openssh.plist</string>
  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
    <string>/usr/local/sbin/sshd</string>
  </array>
  <key>RunAtLoad</key>
  <true/>
  <key>KeepAlive</key>
  <true/>
</dict>
</plist>